# Retrieving bytes from SQL database but getting wrong values

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have added a hash and salt function into my application and that works fine, but once I store the byte[] array into my database and then try to retrieve it, it gets me the wrong value and each time the retrieved value is different.

This is the to store data in the byte array into the database.

```
        String query = "INSERT INTO `teach`.`users`(`id`, `forename`, `surname`, `email`, `username`, `salt`, `password`, `type`) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement registerStatement = null;
    try {
        registerStatement = ServerProgram.getDatabase().getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        registerStatement.setInt(1, 0);
        registerStatement.setString(2, forename);
        registerStatement.setString(3, surname);
        registerStatement.setString(4, email);
        registerStatement.setString(5, username);
        registerStatement.setBytes(6, salt);
        registerStatement.setBytes(7, hashedPassword);
        registerStatement.setString(8, "student");
        registerStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the code to retrieve it (loginExists is the resultSet)

```
byte[] salt = loginExists.getBytes("salt");
byte[] expectedHash = loginExists.getBytes("password");
```

Comment: is there any way you can directly check the values in DB. if so check if the value in db is changing.. also check if by any chance, you are generating new salts rather than using the one from db (just a thought).

Comment: The value in the database stays constant and new salts aren't being generated as that is handled in a different class which is not even called.

Comment: you can try putting some displays in your code to check the data flow..

Comment: I have print outs of the salt being created and the hashed password, and also when they are retrieved if that's what you mean